# I want to use User input from PySimpleGUI to one of my output Excel file name

Tags: python, pandas, pysimplegui

I wanted to use User input from PYSimpleGUI to one of my output **Excel file name** in Python.
I am getting error:

> str1=(sg.Text["-IN4-"])
> TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
import logging
---
---
g.theme("DarkTeal9")
layout = [[sg.T("")], [sg.Text("Data File:      "), sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse(key="-IN1-")],
          [sg.T("")],   [sg.Text("Output Path: "), sg.Input(), sg.FolderBrowse(key="-IN3-")],
          **[sg.T("")],   [sg.Text("PID:             "), sg.Input(),sg.Text(key="-IN4-")]**,
          [[sg.T("")],sg.Button("Submit")]]
--- 
---
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if (event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event == 'Exit') :
        exit()
    elif event == "Submit":
        print(values["-IN1-"])
        print(values["-IN3-"])
        loaddata1=pd.read_excel(values["-IN1-"])
        **str1=(sg.Text["-IN4-"])**
        window.minimize()
        break
---
---
---
**loaddata1.to_excel(values["-IN3-"]+"\ " +f"str1"+"_Data_with_Flags.xlsx", index=0)**
```

I want output file name as **userinput**_Data_with_Flags

Please do correct if my code is wrong.

Comment: `str1 = values["-IN4-"]`

Comment: Hi Jason, I tried this one and its giving below error now.

str1 = values["-IN4-"]
KeyError: '-IN4-'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the row of elements with the sg.Text(key="-IN4-"), like so:

```py
[sg.T("")],   [sg.Text("PID:             "), sg.Input(key="-IN4-")],
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for saving my day. It really help to name my Excel. Really thankful for such quick gesture.

Comment: You're welcome. Enjoy!